# Sequential circuit design

Tags: logic, state-machine, fsm

A sequential circuit has two inputs, x1 and x2. Five-bit sequences  representing decimal digits coded in the 2-out-of-5 code appear from time to time on line a:,, synchronized with a clock pulse on a third line. Each five consecutive bits on the line x1, which occur while x2 = 0 but immediately following one or more inputs of x2 = 1, may be considered a code word. The single output z is to be 0, except upon the fifth bit of an invalid code word. Determine a state table of the above sequential circuit.
2 out of 5 code

- 0=00011
- 1=00101
- 2=00110
- 3=01001
- 4=01010
- 5=01100
- 6=10001
- 7=10010
- 8=10100
- 9=11000

I have solved it with 16 states. could any one tell me the is it possible to reduces the number of states to less than 16?